# Can omitting or duplicating columns/rows be expressed by linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Is there a formal way of algebraically expressing ( for example as a product of specially designed matrices) - duplicating specific row/column(s) or alternatively omitting rows/columns ?

for example I want to able to relate matrices A and B, where $$ A= \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      a&a&a&b&b\\
      a&b&b&a&b
    \end{array}  
\right] $$ and  $$ B=\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      a&b&b\\
      b&a&b
    \end{array}  
\right] $$ where the only operation is omission or duplication of vectors.

Could be a simple operation but it's beyond me.

Comment: Can you edit in an example of what you are trying to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I always use something along the lines of $R_m := R_n$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rule of thumb: if you want a matrix that does something to the rows via left-multiplication, do that thing to the identity matrix. If you want a matrix that does something to the columns via right-multiplication, do that thing to the identity matrix.

For example: say we want to duplicate the second row of a matrix with $3$ rows. The associated matrix would be
$$
R= \pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1}
$$
which is simply the size-3 identity matrix with a duplicated second row.